# Oracle query to get a relational dataset result from multimensional table

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a data table that is multi-dimensional / non-relational. I am trying to write a query that dynamically writes out all the columns names and arrange the data relationally.

The example is a simple table that shows 5 books. The columns show the sizes of the pages in the book. The result set I am looking for would have 3 columns: BOOK_ID, PAGE, PAGE_SIZE. I have included simple code to construct the table.

I have managed to work around by using a union query but this is not reasonable for a massive amount of columns. The dataset has almost 100 columns.

```
CREATE TABLE 
    BOOK_PAGE_SIZE 
        ( 
          BOOK_ID VARCHAR2(5)
        , SIZE_PAGE_1 NUMBER 
        , SIZE_PAGE_2 NUMBER
        , SIZE_PAGE_3 NUMBER
        , SIZE_PAGE_4 NUMBER
        , SIZE_PAGE_5 NUMBER
        );


INSERT INTO BOOK_PAGE_SIZE  VALUES ('T7001',10,35,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO BOOK_PAGE_SIZE  VALUES ('T7002',45,84,78,0,0);
INSERT INTO BOOK_PAGE_SIZE  VALUES ('T7003',28,65,12,32,0);
INSERT INTO BOOK_PAGE_SIZE  VALUES ('T7004',94,74,69,21,76);
INSERT INTO BOOK_PAGE_SIZE  VALUES ('T7005',91,23,14,61,46);
```

RESULT SET:

```
  BOOK_ID  PAGE_NUMBER  PAGE_SIZE
   T70001     Page 1       10
   T70001     Page 2       35
   T70001     Page 3        0
   T70001     Page 4        0
   T70001     Page 5        0
   T70002     Page 1       45
   T70002     Page 2       84
   T70002     Page 3       78
   T70002     Page 4        0
   T70002     Page 5        0
   T70003     Page 1       28
   T70003     Page 2       65
   T70003     Page 3       12
   T70003     Page 4       32
   T70003     Page 5        0
   T70004     Page 1       94
   T70004     Page 2       74
   T70004     Page 3       69
   T70004     Page 4       21
   T70004     Page 5       76
   T70005     Page 1       91
   T70005     Page 2       23
   T70005     Page 3       14
   T70005     Page 4       61
   T70005     Page 5       46
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unpivot` :

```
select *
  from  
  (
   with book_page_size(book_id,size_page_1,size_page_2,size_page_3,size_page_4,size_page_5) as
   (
    select 'T7001', 10, 35,  0,  0,  0 from dual union all
    select 'T7002', 45, 84, 78,  0,  0 from dual union all
    select 'T7003', 28, 65, 12, 32,  0 from dual union all
    select 'T7004', 94, 74, 69, 21, 76 from dual union all
    select 'T7005', 91, 23, 14, 61, 46 from dual 
   )
   select *
     from book_page_size a
  ) 
  unpivot (page_size for page_number in (size_page_1 as 'Page 1',
                                         size_page_2 as 'Page 2',
                                         size_page_3 as 'Page 3',
                                         size_page_4 as 'Page 4',
                                         size_page_5 as 'Page 5'))
  order by book_id, page_number;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2fee1429afae4c96a2bb186f128c2b72)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

As Barbaros Özhan answered, UNPIVOT looks like the good tool for this job, and it takes less code. Also, you can use a SQL query to generate the query you want! I do this often. I've created a table with 20 SIZE_PAGE* columns to demonstrate.

```
select 'select book_id, ''Page ''||page_number as page_number, page_size from book_page_size' txt from dual union all
select 'unpivot (' from dual union all
select '  page_size for page_number in (' from dual union all
select '    ' || column_name || ' as ' || replace(column_name, 'SIZE_PAGE_') ||
case when lead(column_id) over(order by column_id) is not null
  then ','
end
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'BOOK_PAGE_SIZE'
and column_name != 'BOOK_ID'
union all
select ')) u' from dual union all
select 'order by u.book_id, u.page_number' from dual;
```

Running this I get the following query back:

```
select book_id, 'Page '||page_number as page_number, page_size from book_page_size
unpivot (
  page_size for page_number in (
    SIZE_PAGE_1 as 1,
    SIZE_PAGE_2 as 2,
    SIZE_PAGE_3 as 3,
    SIZE_PAGE_4 as 4,
    SIZE_PAGE_5 as 5,
    SIZE_PAGE_6 as 6,
    SIZE_PAGE_7 as 7,
    SIZE_PAGE_8 as 8,
    SIZE_PAGE_9 as 9,
    SIZE_PAGE_10 as 10,
    SIZE_PAGE_11 as 11,
    SIZE_PAGE_12 as 12,
    SIZE_PAGE_13 as 13,
    SIZE_PAGE_14 as 14,
    SIZE_PAGE_15 as 15,
    SIZE_PAGE_16 as 16,
    SIZE_PAGE_17 as 17,
    SIZE_PAGE_18 as 18,
    SIZE_PAGE_19 as 19,
    SIZE_PAGE_20 as 20
)) u
order by u.book_id, u.page_number
```

When I run the query, the result is:

```
BOOK_ID   PAGE_NUMBER  PAGE_SIZE   
BK001     Page 1               1 
BK001     Page 2               2 
BK001     Page 3               3 
BK001     Page 4               4 
BK001     Page 5               5 
BK001     Page 6               6 
BK001     Page 7               7 
BK001     Page 8               8 
BK001     Page 9               9 
BK001     Page 10             10 
BK001     Page 11             11 
BK001     Page 12             12 
BK001     Page 13             13 
BK001     Page 14             14 
BK001     Page 15             15 
BK001     Page 16             16 
BK001     Page 17             17 
BK001     Page 18             18 
BK001     Page 19             19 
BK001     Page 20             20
```

Comment: Beautiful, this really helped. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use some union all

```
    select  BOOK_ID,  'Page 1'  PAGE_NUMBER, SIZE_PAGE_1 PAGE_SIZE
    from  BOOK_PAGE_SIZE 
    union all  
    select  BOOK_ID,  'Page 2'  , SIZE_PAGE_2
    from  BOOK_PAGE_SIZE 
    union all  
    select  BOOK_ID,  'Page 3'  , SIZE_PAGE_3
    from  BOOK_PAGE_SIZE 
    union all  
    select  BOOK_ID,  'Page 4'  , SIZE_PAGE_4
    from  BOOK_PAGE_SIZE 
    union all  
    select  BOOK_ID,  'Page 5'  , SIZE_PAGE_5
    from  BOOK_PAGE_SIZE 
    order by BOOK_ID PAGE_NUMBER, PAGE_SIZE
```

but you should not use  set of column you should normalize your schema

Comment: This was my first idea, however, this becomes unreasonable when you are looking at more than 100 columns. Nice idea though, that's what I currently have.

Comment: ideally I would want the table normalized, however the system that outputs the data does so with this structure. We are working to get a development out to change this but in the mean time a viable workaround is required. Your answer as I mentioned before is valid, just too laborious.